# Trying to create a node_type in DP 7

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm trying to create a simple node_type in drupal 7 based on the core blog module.

This is my hook_install:

```
function node_link_install() {
  node_types_rebuild();
  $types = node_type_get_types();
  node_add_body_field($types['node_link']);
}
```

and this is then the hook_info in my node_link.module file:

```
function node_link_node_info() {
  return array(
    'node_link' => array(
      'name' => t('Node Link'),
      'base' => 'node_link',
      'description' => t('Just playing around'),
    )
  );
}
```

and here is my hook_uninstall:

```
function node_link_uninstall() {
  $result = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type", array(':type' => 'node_link'));

  $nids = array();

  foreach ($result as $item) {
    array_push($nids, $item->nid);
  }

  if (count($nids)) {
    node_delete_multiple($nids);
  }

  drupal_uninstall_schema('node_link');
}
```

when I try to install the above module I get:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: node_link in node_link_install() (line 10 of
> ```
>
> drupal/sites/all/modules/custom/node_link/node_link.install).
>       Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in node_add_body_field() (line 555 of
>   drupal/modules/node/node.module).
>       Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in node_add_body_field() (line 568 of
>   drupal/modules/node/node.module).
>       FieldException: Attempt to create an instance of field body without a bundle. in field_create_instance() (line 460 of
>   drupal/modules/field/field.crud.inc).

Several things are puzzling me here:

1) why does this work for the blog module but not my module?

2) when I uninstall this module, the entry in the system table is not deleted

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is complaining that it can't save the body field because you haven't specified the bundle of the object. But more importantly I think you want to look into the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) rather than creating a 'node_type'.

In drupal there are nodes and there are types of nodes called content types. To make it more abstract, nodes are entities of type 'node'.  Each content type is a 'bundle' of that entity type. Many things in drupal are entities, from users to comments to taxonomies.

If all you want to do is create a content type programatically, I think [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) might have one. Otherwise just create the content type through configuration.

Comment: Looks like the entity api actually is what I was looking for